# Double null value union php

Tags: php, mysql, null, union, union-all

I have a question about the null value with union i have this code

```
SELECT NULL,NULL,username, omschrijving, datum, project ,opdrachtgever ,tijd_van,tijd_tot,TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(tijd_tot,tijd_van), '%H:%i') as nosearch_diff
        FROM uren ur
        JOIN projecten AS pr ON pr.project_id = ur.project_id   
        JOIN user AS us ON us.userid = ur.userid
        JOIN opdrachtgever AS og ON pr.opdrachtgever_id = og.opdrachtgever_id
        UNION 
        SELECT  materiaal,afdeling,username, omschrijving, datum, project  ,opdrachtgever ,tijd_van,tijd_tot,TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(tijd_tot,tijd_van), '%H:%i') as nosearch_diff
        FROM materiaal AS ma
        JOIN projecten AS pr ON pr.project_id = ma.project_id
        JOIN user AS us ON us.userid = ma.userid
        JOIN opdrachtgever AS op ON op.opdrachtgever_id = pr.opdrachtgever_id
        JOIN afdeling AS af ON af.afdeling_id = ma.afdeling_id
        JOIN materiaalnaam AS mt ON mt.materiaalnaam_id = ma.materiaalnaam_id
```

the query is working fine but i have 1 problem. The first query has a double NULL value and it refers to the second query materiaal and afdeling
but if i want to display it it only shows the value from afdelingen in the first NULL and the second NULL for example:

lets say that afdeling = Shipping and materiaal Boat.

it display's like this:

```
NULL : Shipping 

NULL : Shipping
```

But i want it to display like:

```
NULL : Shipping

NULL : Boat
```

does anybody know how to fix this issue

Thanks, 
Kevin

Comment: Can you Provide some sample data.

Comment: Well it's only about the null values i just want it to display materiaal and afdeling like i said afdeling = Shipping - materiaal = Boat now it just displays 2 times Shipping

Comment: Do you mean that you have duplicate rows in the first query result?

Comment: Yes i doesn't get materiaal only afdeling so it returns 2 times shipping in the view.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it i have just give them NULL value a name 
example:

```
NULL AS materiaal ,NULL AS afdeling
```

This is the way how you can fix it.

Thanks Guys!